# Internet "entities" validation using Java

Tags: java

Are there FOSS libraries to perform validation on Internet objects like:

- domain name (is it valid? character-set, length, etc.)
- e-mail address (user and domain components)
- internet port numbers? (in the range 0..2^16-1, etc.)
- etc.

Examples:

```
Domains.isValid(domainName);
IpPorts.isValid(portNumber);
EmailAddresses.isValid(emailAddress);
ImapFolderNames.isValid(imapFolderName);
UnixUsernames.isValid(username);
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/). You can, for example, use the [EmailValidator class](http://commons.apache.org/validator/api-1.4.0/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html) there.

Comment: Looks _very_ good, although incomplete. Thanks! I am upvoting but not accepting yet, in case there is another framework doing more "complete" validation... (this does very nicely URL, email, domain name, ... so it's pretty good actually, don't get me wrong)